# Implementing Recursive descent algorithm for PWL Approximation

Tags: recursive-algorithms, linear-approximation

I am currently trying to linearise a convex function at hand (an M/M/1 curve) using piecewise linear functions. Since I wanted the approximation error to be as low as possible, I searched for some algorithms that do it and found the 'Recursive descent algorithm' by Imamoto to be the most suited one. The algorithm intends to find a minimax solution of PWL approximation.

However, I've run into some trouble implementing the algorithm. I don't understand a particular block of the algorithm which says

$\epsilon = 0.5 * max/min |^{N-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{i,j}$

I'm really sorry for asking such a trivial question, but I don't know how to implement this particular block in my code. Could you please help me out?

The link to the paper is [here.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Benjamim_Tang/publication/251882990_A_Recursive_Descent_Algorithm_for_Finding_the_Optimal_Minimax_Piecewise_Linear_Approximation_of_Convex_Functions/links/555659e508ae6943a8733b70.pdf)

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just asking for the worst case error, keeping its sign: from the set $\{\varepsilon_{i,J} : 0 \leq i \leq N-1\}$, find the one with the maximum modulus, divide it by $2$, and set $\varepsilon$ equal to that.  The $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is to transform the $g_i$ we have (as in figure 2) to the $g_i$ we want (as in figure 1).  (If we remove half the endpoint error from the entire linear piece, the tangent point error increases to match the decreased endpoint error.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric (its my fav SP character name :)). But, why does the notation have to be max/min while we only intend to find the one with maximum modulus?  Also, at the block where we find$e_{i,j}$, isn't the interval supposed to be between 0 and N-1 (as we only have 0 to N-1 segments and not 0 to N)?

Comment: @crypto : $N-1$ segments gives $N$ knots -- ([fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)).  Of course, the error of the last two knots is (supposed to be) the same, so ... whichever.

Comment: @crypto -- this is the maximum of the positive errors or the minumum of the negative errors, whichever has the larger modulus.  So you don't know whether you took a maximum or a minimum unless you already know the sign of the error of largest modulus.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation eric.